# Python: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and I'm trying to make a function that stores the name of visited pages in `request.session`. However I keep getting the error "'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'" on the line where I try to append a variable to `request.session['visited_pages']` I searched online and I didn't find anything that solved the problem, I did find that you can't append directly to `request.session['visited_pages']`, instead you have to make a separate array. I did that but that didn't fix my problem. Here is my code:

```
def index(request):
    visited_pages = get_visited_pages(request)
    context = {
        "visited_pages": visited_pages
    }
    return render(request, 'website/index.html', context)

def get_visited_pages(request):
    current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

    if not 'visited_pages' in request.session or not request.session['visited_pages']:
        request.session['visited_pages'] = current_url
    else:
        visited_pages_array = request.session['visited_pages']
        visited_pages_array.append(current_url)
        request.session['visited_pages'] = visited_pages_array

    return request.session['visited_pages']
```

Comment: can you tell the output of `print(visited_pages)` and `print(type(visited_pages))`?

Comment: @MYGz I can't print anything on the page because of the error

Comment: Comment out the append line. Insert a print above it.

Comment: @MYGz value is index (which is good) and type is 'unicode'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
request.session['visited_pages'] = current_url
```

with:

```
request.session['visited_pages'] = [current_url]
```

so that `visited_pages` item in the session is a `list` and not a `unicode` object.

You will also need to modify any code that depends on or calls `get_visited_pages` because we have changed the return value from `unicode` to `list`.

Comment: This fixed it after flushing the session! Thank you :)